# Using Java to Verify a Password Hashed using password_hash in PHP

Tags: java, php, hash, password-hash, php-password-hash

I have a PHP-based web application that sends HTTP requests to a Java Web Service which in turn performs the actions requested in an Oracle database. I want to use password_hash to hash my password before sending it in the HTTP request. If I do this on creating new user, there is no problem there. However, when I need to login using this password, I can't verify it in PHP because I don't (and can't) have direct access to the database to be able to get the hash stored there. So the verification has to be in the Java Web Service. Is that possible and if not, what's the alternative? The salt being used would be random so I can't hash the password being used for login and send that because I don't have the salt used for the hash stored in the database.

Comment: so in production you got one server with php, and another server somewhere else with a java web service and a database, right?

Comment: Most probably yes (although they can be on the same server). The "can't have direct access to the db in PHP" part is a requirement for security reasons. We can't have db connection info or statements in the PHP code.

Comment: Each salt will be random for each user, but inorder to verify the login, the salt needs to be stored in the db with the password, `<random-salt><hashed-password>`. When I user attempts login, the username can be used to retrieve the salt from the database. Multiple messages will be needed for authentication between the web services and PHP app. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33505/why-using-random-salts http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16325/hashed-password-storage-with-random-salt

Comment: Could you not connect to the Java service using HTTPS and just forward the username/password exactly as the PHP script received them from the user... they'll still be SSL (well, TLS) encrypted in much the same way they were between the user's machine and the PHP server.

Answer (score 0):

Place you login as a service on the web service, add a check on the login function so only the PHP server can access it (I assume the entire service can only be accessed by the PHP server anyway, that's why you have the PHP server separated in the first place). The login will have to be refreshed (ping) every once in a while for the session to remain open, all operations on the service will check this session to be alive, have a java agent closing idle connections if you web service only runs on pull/push.

You will have to take the boring task of relaying the login from the user through php to the web service and do the login entirely there, then back to php and start serving once the user has been authenticated.

If THAT is the security risk (you dont want PHP to even have the hash of the password) then you have to have the user login to the web service on their own then contact you, validate the user is the logged user and start service.

As for hashes and salts, they are used to protect encrypted data on the database from being stolen and read. (on its simplest form, to protect credit card numbers). The salt can be public, the hash technically too, but you'll have to protect it with SSL as least so no one can login using it (or the plain password if your user sends that) :P. plain password > hash , then add salt > both salt and result stored to database.

In case PHP relays login data, then PHP can hold its side of the session since it knows the identity of the user with the cookie+browser agent+ip (still needs to keep a session open with the service). In the case the user logins to the web service directly, PHP has to request that info to the web service (ip+browser agent if possible) or request a session token (a string generated by the service), that has to be supplied by the user if he wants to access any page on the PHP server for the duration of the token.